# Rails: patch ActionCable (add new adapter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Question refers to this pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/23211

Since it has not been merged yet, I want to monkey patch this into my application.

I put this subscription adapter to `lib/core_extenstions/subsctiption_adapter/test.rb`

Now, in initialize `monkey_patch.rb` I try:

```
#require  'lib/action_cable/test.rb'
#autoload ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Test
module ActionCable
  module SubscriptionAdapter
    puts Rails.root.join('lib/core_extensions/action_cable/test.rb').inspect
    autoload :Test, Rails.root.join('lib/core_extensions/action_cable/test.rb')
    puts Test.inspect
  end
end
```

Then:

```
MacBook-Pro-Vaceslav:mvp_c slava$ bundle exec rails c test
Running via Spring preloader in process 93788
Loading test environment (Rails 5.0.2)
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
irb(main):001:0> server = ActionCable.server
=> #<ActionCable::Server::Base:0x007f890e812628 @mutex=#<Monitor:0x007f890e812600 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007f890e8125b0>>, @pubsub=nil, @worker_pool=nil, @event_loop=nil, @remote_connections=nil>
irb(main):002:0> server.pubsub
LoadError: Could not load 'action_cable/subscription_adapter/test'. Make sure that the adapter in config/cable.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'postgresql' or 'redis' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
```

So source of issue is here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/lib/action_cable/server/configuration.rb

```
def pubsub_adapter
    adapter = (cable.fetch("adapter") { "redis" })
    path_to_adapter = "action_cable/subscription_adapter/#{adapter}"
    begin
      require path_to_adapter
    rescue Gem::LoadError => e
      raise Gem::LoadError, "Specified '#{adapter}' for Action Cable pubsub adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem '#{e.name}'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by Action Cable)."
    rescue LoadError => e
      raise LoadError, "Could not load '#{path_to_adapter}'. Make sure that the adapter in config/cable.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'postgresql' or 'redis' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.", e.backtrace
    end

    adapter = adapter.camelize
    adapter = "PostgreSQL" if adapter == "Postgresql"
    "ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::#{adapter}".constantize
  end
```

Not sure how to workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite bad I suppose, but don't see any other way with this implementation other than:

```
module ActionCable
  module Server
    class Configuration
      def pubsub_adapter
        if Rails.env == 'test'
          require Rails.root.join('lib/core_extensions/action_cable/test.rb')
          ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Test
        else
          super
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any improvements are welcome.

**EDIT**

possibly much better way is to stub it needed test suits:

```
  before do
    ActionCable.server.instance_variable_set(:@pubsub, ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Test)
  end
```